# AWS RDS: how to monitor data transfer out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using an RDS MySQL Instance on AWS (Amazon Web Services). The RDS sits on a public subnet as I need to write to this database over the internet from an external PC. Further I write queries in programs like java and python to pull data that sits on this MySQL Database. What I would like to know is how I can monitor how much data I am reading / querying from the RDS instance. I know AWS charges me per GB of data per month and I query the database a lot so this statistic would be helpful.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The place to start would be in the [CloudTrail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) service, which lets you log service requests.  Here is a link to the RDS-specific documentation:

- *[Logging Amazon RDS API Calls Using AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Auditing.html)*